# Block user roles from accessing the WordPress dashboard

Tags: user-roles, dashboard

I want to block multiple user roles from accessing the WordPress dashboard, I have a custom role, and I want to block it along with other roles, but I don't know how to edit the code.

the code below has one role (shopkeeper) I want to add more roles how can I do that?

```
function wpse66094_no_admin_access() {
    $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url( '/' );
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    if($user_role === 'shopkeeper'){
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
    }
 }

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse66094_no_admin_access', 100 );
```

Comment: have a look at `in_array()`. Also `exit()` expects a string or int parameter while `wp_redirect()` returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array of the roles that need to be blocked, and use [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect) to check if the current user is in any of those roles.

```
function wpse66094_no_admin_access() {
    $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url( '/' );
    global $current_user;
    $blocked_roles = array( 
        'shopkeeper',
        'block-this-role',
        'block-this-role-too'
    );
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    // If the user is in any of the blocked roles, redirect 'em.
    if ( ! empty( array_intersect( $user_roles, $blocked_roles ) ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
        exit;
    }
 }

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse66094_no_admin_access', 100 );
```

Thanks to @Cornell Raiu in the comments for correcting the [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) / `exit` code, and @TomJNowell for recommending [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/).

Comment: `exit()` expects a string or int parameter while `wp_redirect()` returns a string.

Comment: Touché, I was copy-n-pasting the OP's code. Will fix, thanks.

Comment: `wp_safe_redirect` would be safer, and `in_array` would be a simpler check than `empty( array_intersect(`, I'd also use `[]` instead of `array()` and update the function name to use `408112` for the new question

Comment: Hi @Pat J, I got an error when I used the code after adding the other roles.

Comment: @TomJNowell I considered using `in_array()` but in the case of a user with multiple roles, `array_intersect()` will catch any of the blocked roles in any of the user's roles. (The originally posted code only appears to check one of the user's possible roles.)

Comment: @KDot I missed a `)` in my code. It should be fixed now.